# Cell automation with text in excel

Tags: excel, function, text

[This is the Excel spreadsheet I'm trying to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOARP.png)

My goal is to be able to automate the completed column with the previous answers corresponding to the cells prior to the completed cell and after the name's cell.

To put it simply. I do not know how to get the complete cell to output Yes or No autmatically if the whole row is completly filled with yes or No 
Does one know a suitable solution where IT HAS TO Be THE WHOLE ROW that determines the Completed column?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the "complete" column

```
=IF(AND(B1="Yes";C1="Yes";D1="Yes";E1="Yes";F1="Yes");"Yes";"No")
```

Instead of B1, C1 etc. use your Column and Row identifier